# Debugging in fdt

Tags: flash, fdt

the document class of my .fla file has a lot of references to elements on the stage, I use fdt for the .as, but everytime I need to debug I have to switch back to Flash IDE, I read this tutorial (http://www.sebastian-weyrauch.de/tutorials/fdt_debugging_tutorial/), but I think it assumes no .fla is involved.

So, How could I debug my project with fdt and keep working with the Flash IDE just for the graphic part?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good tutorial for FDT and Flash IDE Integration:
http://www.iamrocco.net/fdt-and-flash-ide-integration/

Answer (score 1):

I spend long time to figure this out.
The best solution is compile Flash assets into SWC file library (insetad SWF).
Just remember to export all required symbols in Flash (Right click on symbol export to actionscript)
Then copy you swc file (or best directly publish) into FDT libs folder.

Then you can simply create new instances of classes create in Flash inside FDT.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more, the Powerflasher FDT website has a good list of excellent community tutorials:
http://www.fdt.powerflasher.com/developer-tools/fdt-3/getting-started/tutorials/